# Create JSON object from list of variables using python

Tags: python, json

Trying to create JSON output from list of variables

Using below method. It's working fine. But not able to change the key names with list of variables.

```
import json
from collections import namedtuple
from json import JSONEncoder

import sys
var1 = sys.argv[1]
var2 = sys.argv[2]
var3 = sys.argv[3]
var4 = sys.argv[4]
var5 = sys.argv[5]
var6 = sys.argv[6]
var7 = sys.argv[7]

class Key:
    def __init__(self, keys):
        self.keys = keys

class ChildKey:
    def __init__(self, A, B, C, D, E):
        self.A, self.B, self.C, self.D, self.E = A, B, C, D, E

class ChildValue:
    def __init__(self, ABC, XYZ):
        self.ABC, self.XYZ = ABC, XYZ

class JsonEncoder(JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, o):
            return o.__dict__

childvalue = ChildValue(var1, var2)
childkey = ChildKey(var3, var4, var5, var6, childvalue)
keys = Key(childkey)

# dumps() produces JSON in native str format. if you want to writ it in file use dump()
customJson = json.dumps(keys, indent=4, cls=JsonEncoder, sort_keys=False)
print(customJson)
```

variables from shell script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="123"
b="456"
c="name1"
d="name2"
e="name3"
f="name4"
g="C"

python test.py $a $b $c $d $e $f $g
```

I am getting an output as below:

```
{
    "keys": {
        "A": "name1",
        "C": "name3",
        "B": "name2",
        "E": {
            "XYZ": "456",
            "ABC": "123"
        },
        "D": "name4"
    }
}
```

But want the keys i.e, A,B,C,D replace with other shell variables. something like:

```
{
    "keys": {
        "X": "name1",
        "Y": "name3",
        "Z": "name2",
        "2": {
            "XYZ": "456",
            "ABC": "123"
        },
        "1": "name4"
    }
}
```

NOt sure how to achieve that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you just want to prepend the key names with `new_`?

Comment: want to replace those with new values from shell script

Comment: what do you mean by new values? The only difference between your current output and the output you want is that the keys have `new_` prepended.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: I still really don't understand the question, hopefully someone else does

Comment: want to replace A,B,C,D with other values

Comment: If possible let me know how to prepend with "new_". I want to modify the keys names @jordanm

Comment: If you want key `X` instead of `A`, then rename the variable.  Use `self.X` instead of `self.A`.

Comment: can't do that, need to use this as schema, then replace with new values

Comment: you could make a mapping dictionary and apply the values to found keys from that

Comment: @TenaciousB, any example could you please provide